# What does the word 「すみっちょ」 mean?

Tags: words, dialects

Here is the sentence including the word.

> あぶねえ！　へやの**すみっちょ**にいってろ

I have found an entry read 隅{すみ}**っこ** meaning 'corner' but I'm not sure if it is the same meaning as the word in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it means すみっこ. They say it's [静岡{しずおか}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9D%99%E5%B2%A1%E7%9C%8C) dialect. [Source 1](http://muhihouse.com/Japanese/2007/03/post_10.html)・[Source 2](http://mixi.jp/view_bbs.pl?comm_id=190872&id=6178583)